# boost::process write to stdin

Tags: c++, boost, process, stdin

I have a thread starting a boost::process application, with the code the thread runs like this:

```
void Service::Run()
{
    printf("Starting thread for service ID %i\n", this->sid);

    // Set up a stream sink for stdout, stderr and stdin
    bprocess::pipe pstdIn    = create_pipe();
    bprocess::pipe pstdOut   = create_pipe();
    file_descriptor_sink      fdSink(pstdIn.sink, close_handle);
    file_descriptor_source    fdSrc(pstdOut.sink, close_handle);

    // Set up the read write streams
    this->stdIn  = new fdistream(fdSink);
    this->stdOut = new fdostream(fdSrc);

    // Execute the service
    try
    {
        child proc = execute(
            set_args(this->args),
            inherit_env(),
            bind_stdin(fdSrc),

            throw_on_error()
        );

        printf("PID: %i\n", proc.pid);

        // Wait for the application to end then call a cleanup function
        int exit_code = wait_for_exit(proc);

        printf("Service died, error code: %i\n", exit_code);
    }
    catch(boost::system::system_error err)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong: %s\n", err.what());
    }

    this->manager->ServiceDie(this->sid);

    return;
}
```

As this function is a blocking one, it essentially waits for the service to be killed (Externally or as I need; input via stdin to gracefully stop the application).

I have no idea how to write to the stdin of the child process. I have tried this:

```
*(this->stdIn) << "stop\n";
```

inside a public function in the class of `Service` that's being called in another thread (`Manager` class). However this yeilds no results.

How can I write to the stdin of the child `proc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo adapted from sample [here](http://www.highscore.de/cpp/process/#communicating):

<strike>You can see it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce0542299e0a1245)**</strike> Sadly that's pushing the limits of Coliru. May be later:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp> 
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost::process; 

int main() 
{ 
    std::string exec = find_executable_in_path("rev"); 
    std::vector<std::string> args = boost::assign::list_of("rev"); 

    context ctx; 
    ctx.environment = self::get_environment(); 
    ctx.stdin_behavior = capture_stream(); 
    ctx.stdout_behavior = capture_stream(); 
    child c = launch(exec, args, ctx); 

    postream &os = c.get_stdin();
    pistream &is = c.get_stdout(); 

    os << "some\ncookies\nfor\ntasting";
    os.close();

    std::cout << is.rdbuf(); 
}
```

Output:

```
emos
seikooc
rof
gnitsat
```

Now, if you need it *truly* asynchronous, there's another sample using Boost Asio further [down that page](http://www.highscore.de/cpp/process/#communicating)

Comment: For some reason, I don't have `get_stdin()` function...not sure why, oh I don't have `launch()` either.

Comment: Bah, in my response I forgot to mention what version of Boost::Process I had...I had an old version (0.5). I have updated and I will try this all again. Thanks for the helpful answer though!!

Comment: @Zinglish Are you sure that version 0.5 is old? Which version are you using right now?